# 'Accordion' <p> elements blocking Shopify buy button

Tags: html, css, shopify

I have some hidden p elements that are revealed upon clicking a checkbox.
For some reason, while hidden, the p elements are still 'above' the buy button and therefore it cannot be clicked until both checkboxes are checked.

The issue is live [HERE](https://levelsbarbers.co.uk/121.html)

I've tried messing with the height value for .hiddentext, and z-index values but no luck.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Set your ```visibility``` to ```hidden``` instead of none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visibility: none;` is an invalid value, instead set it like this:

```
.accordion p {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```